# jQuery Statment not working in separate file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include, head

somehow my simple jQuery Statement is not working when I include it in my "head"-element topic like :

```
<script src="js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I use it in my "body"-element it just works fine like

```
<script>
  $( "#testid" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
</script>
```

I checked already with firebug that my test.js file gets included on my site correctly. So what do I wrong ? The test.js file looks exactly like the "script" part above just without the script-tags.

Any idea is appreciated :)

Comment: wrap your code inside document's ready event..@!

Comment: are you adding the test.js after jquery min file??

Comment: Make sure you include it in head after jQuery.

Comment: Rajaprabhu just hit it - it was always included after jquery btw.

Comment: You are changing two different things (head/body and inline/external file) and blaming the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to tell `jQuery` to wait until the `DOM ready` before firing up your code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#testid" ).click(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});
```

When you include your code in the body tag **after the target element** your code will work. However, if you include it in the body section **before the target element** or **in the head section** your code would not work. It is therefore recommended to always wrap your code in `DOM ready`. `DOM ready` can be written in different ways:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$( document ).ready( handler )
$().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)
$( handler )
```

Check out the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/, 
and the tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Kris was your comment meant for my answer or the one that's just been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like I rip of Rajaprabhu but:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $( "#testid" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#testid" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  });
});

</script>
```

Also make sure your script has been added after jquery scipt.